# Simple Create Table error

Tags: mysql

I don't understand why I am getting an error at the dateCreated line.

```
CREATE TABLE 'MediaContent'(

media_id int(11),
tag varchar(255),
dateCreated varchar(255),
title varchar(255),
subtitle varchar(255),
rating int(1),
dataLocation varchar(255)
PRIMARY KEY (media_id)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use backticks to escape column and table names, not quotes

```
CREATE TABLE `MediaContent`
(
    media_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    tag varchar(255),
    dateCreated varchar(255),
    title varchar(255),
    subtitle varchar(255),
    rating int(1),
    dataLocation varchar(255)
)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Seems non-conventional to do backticks instead of quotes. What do you mean escape? Any reason why they chose this? I'm just curious now. Thanks again, Cheers! @juergen d

Comment: You only need backticks when you use [reserved words of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Using backticks *escapes* the names and the engine knows that you don't mean the keyword, but your table name.

Comment: BTW quotes are for strings.